# Insert into with dynamic column names?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query with bound parameters for the values for inserting data into a table.  I am using PDO.  The idea is that I have an invoice with an order number, date, time, etc.  The invoice has a list of products with their quantities, however the # of unique products varies from one invoice to another.  As a result that means the # of columns the quantities will be inserted into will vary from invoice to invoice. Invoice A with 4 products will be inserting data into 4 columns vs invoice B with 5 products which will be dealing with 5 products.

```
$sth = conn->prepare("INSERT INTO test1 (col_1, col_2, col_3) VALUES (:order, :date, :time)");

$sth->bindParam(':order', $orderID);
$sth->bindParam(':date', $date);
$sth->bindParam(':time', $time);

$sth->execute();
```

This query works and inserts whatever values I have for the variables into the appropriate columns.  How can I have the columns function similar to a bound parameter too?

When I tried something like below it did not work.

```
 $sth = conn->prepare("INSERT INTO test1 (:col1, :col2) VALUES (:order, :date, :time)");

  $sth->bindParam(':order', $orderID);
  $sth->bindParam(':date', $date);
  $sth->bindParam(':time', $time);
  $sth->bindParam(':col1', $col1);
  $sth->bindParam(':col2', $col2);
```

I made the values for the variables $col1 and $col2 column names names in the test1 table.  I came across this post in my search while I tried to solve this issue which helped somewhat.

[Can PHP PDO Statements accept the table or column name as parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-or-column-name-as-parameter)

Part of the issue though is that I don't know how many column names I will be inserting into in advance and the above linked idea seems to only work if you know the # of columns in advance.  Any advice on this?

Comment: you can't simple as that.

Comment: What would be an alternative?

Comment: you could use regular old php, but i worry if some one says " I don't know how many column names I will be inserting into in advance" sounds like the db schema is going to be wrong

Comment: The way I have the db setup currently is the following:  TABLE invoices (order_id, date, total_cost).  TABLE upcs (upc_id, product_name) TABLE inventory (order_id,product1, product2, product3, product4) etc.  I am new to trying to setup a DB by myself so if the issue is the db is all wrong I'm happy to fix it.  In my head I figured it would work like insert into inventory (order_id <the columns of the products in that order>) VALUES ($order_id, <values for quantity of the products>);  something like that.

Comment: TABLE inventory should be (order_id, product) with 1 row per product

Comment: How would I show that each order_id has more than 1 product then though?  Wouldn't that end up being like row1:  (orderid: 29498498 product: dogfood)?

Comment: (orderid: 29498498 product: dogfood), (orderid: 29498498 product: catfood) etc.. exactly how it is done.

Comment: this is going to get to broad for S.O i would suggest most tutorials would show you this approach.

Comment: ahh I think I understand now. Then I would have a 3rd separate column for quantity and store the quantity for the item there.   So it would look like (orderid: 2949 product: dogfood quantity:5) (orderid 2949 product: catfood quantity:10).  Everything is still associated with the order number so I would be able to easily run a select to find the information if I wanted to display all items for order 2949.  Thank you.

Comment: look at joins, you can get all the products,invoice and upcs details in one query